# Full screen background with css

Tags: html, css

I am using this code. It  covers the whole background with 1 image. The problem is the upper part of it, which gets cut by browser and the lower part by the taskbar. As i go fullscreen it works fine. I want the image to sit in the browser fully. Is there any method available for that??

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: put this in a jsfiddle please? So that we can see a working demo? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why wouldn't you use CSS's `background` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your current CSS to:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#bg img {
  position: absolute;
  /* display: cover; */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is **[example 1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emrpvY)**.

Alternatively, load the image purely with CSS and set it as background. Change your code  to:

**HTML**

```
 <div id="bg">
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(images/bg.jpg);
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
}
```

Here is **[example 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwrNdq)**.

Both of them will set the image as background.

Comment: sorry but it didn't work; i just want the image to be full fit in browser.

Comment: Both of the above will make the image to fit the browser

Comment: we need to add width: 100%;
  height: 100%; in #bg img then it worked

Answer (score 0):

## Change 1

Remove the

```
 top: -50%; 
 left: -50%;
```

on your code. It makes the hiding of both you mentioned.

## Change 2

You need to declare the image width and height in the

```
#bg img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```